# Fill in feasible region with Fill_between

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, linear-programming

I'm trying to fill in the maximum outward region as attached in the image. Below code will generate the line graph, however, I'm struggling to fill in the region as in the image.[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
x = np.linspace(0,20,2000)
y1 = (-2*x) + 6
y2 = 5-x
y3 = (20 - (2*x))/10
plt.plot(x,y1,label = r'$2x1+x2geq6$')
plt.plot(x,y2,label = r'$x+ygeq5$')
plt.plot(x,y3,label = r'$2x+10ygeq20$')
plt.xlim((0,10))
plt.ylim((0,10))
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')
```

Comment: did you try the `fill_between` method you mention in the title?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way, would be to use the maximum of the 3 curves:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(0, 20, 2000)
y1 = (-2 * x) + 6
y2 = 5 - x
y3 = (20 - (2 * x)) / 10
plt.plot(x, y1, label=r'$2x1+x2geq6$')
plt.plot(x, y2, label=r'$x+ygeq5$')
plt.plot(x, y3, label=r'$2x+10ygeq20$')
plt.fill_between(x, np.amax([y1, y2, y3], axis=0), 10, color='black', alpha=0.3)
plt.xlim((0, 10))
plt.ylim((0, 10))
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')
plt.show()
```

[image: fill_between using max]

Answer (score 0):

You could fill the entire background with a color, then use `fill_between` make the area below the lines white.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = 'lightgrey'

x = np.linspace(0,20,2000)
y1 = (-2*x) + 6
y2 = 5-x
y3 = (20 - (2*x))/10
plt.plot(x,y1,label = r'$2x1+x2geq6$')
plt.plot(x,y2,label = r'$x+ygeq5$')
plt.plot(x,y3,label = r'$2x+10ygeq20$')
plt.xlim((0,10))
plt.ylim((0,10))
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')

plt.fill_between(x,y3, color='white')
plt.fill_between(x,y2, color='white')
plt.fill_between(x,y1, color='white');
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks so much!